# Plotting PMFs and PDFs

Tags: distributions, data-visualization, density-function, likelihood, discrete-data

This is probably a silly question, but I was reading [Computational Statistics with Python](http://people.duke.edu/~ccc14/sta-663/MCMC.html) and there are a few plots describing prior, likelihood and posterior distribution in the context of calculating the bias of a coin given $n$ tosses and $h$ heads. It is using a beta distribution to describe the prior and binomial for the likelihood as usual. The PMF is calculated in the likelihood for several values of $\theta \in [0,1]$ for a given number of heads $h$, that is, `binom(n, thetas).pmf(h)` in a vectorized form. However, there is a factor $n$ (number of trials) multiplying the PMFs:

```
plt.plot(thetas, n*st.binom(n, thetas).pmf(h), label='Likelihood', c='green')
```

That $n$ is the part that I don't understand.

This is the full code:

```
n = 100
h = 61
p = h/n
rv = st.binom(n, p)
mu = rv.mean()

a, b = 10, 10
prior = st.beta(a, b)
post = st.beta(h+a, n-h+b)
ci = post.interval(0.95)

thetas = np.linspace(0, 1, 200)
plt.figure(figsize=(12, 9))
plt.style.use('ggplot')
plt.plot(thetas, prior.pdf(thetas), label='Prior', c='blue')
plt.plot(thetas, post.pdf(thetas), label='Posterior', c='red')
plt.plot(thetas, n*st.binom(n, thetas).pmf(h), label='Likelihood', c='green')
plt.axvline((h+a-1)/(n+a+b-2), c='red', linestyle='dashed', alpha=0.4, label='MAP')
plt.axvline(mu/n, c='green', linestyle='dashed', alpha=0.4, label='MLE')
plt.xlim([0, 1])
plt.axhline(0.3, ci[0], ci[1], c='black', linewidth=2, label='95% CI');
plt.xlabel(r'$\theta$', fontsize=14)
plt.ylabel('Density', fontsize=16)
plt.legend();
```

And the result:

[image]

I understand that maybe the idea is to try to compare a PMF that produces probabilities with a PDF that gives probabilities/unit of length. Unfortunately, I'm not sure I understand why we should multiply by the number of trials.

I would have thought that maybe using CDF to calculate probabilities from a PDF would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

The scaling with $n$ has nothing to do with mass vs. density. It is due to the different domains the prior and the PMF live in, and the differences in their support ranges.

We have a constant $n$ and the likelihood function $f(\theta, h) =$ `st.binom(n, thetas).pmf(h)`, which we want to interprete as a PDF in the $\theta$-domain. To achieve that we have to multiply it with a scaling factor $c$.

We know that
$$\sum_{h=0}^{n} f(\theta, h) \equiv 1$$
$$\int_0^1 \sum_{h=0}^{n} f(\theta, h) \, \text{d}\theta = \int_0^1 1 \, \text{d}\theta = 1$$
because $f(\theta, h)$ is a PMF in the $h$-domain.

However, we are looking for a PDF $p(\theta, h) = c \cdot f(\theta, h)$ in the $\theta$-domain, which requires
$$\int_{0}^1 p(\theta, h) \, \text{d}\theta \equiv 1$$
$$c \cdot \int_{0}^1 \sum_{h=0}^n f(\theta, h) \, \text{d}\theta = \sum_{h=0}^n 1 = n+1$$
Thus, $c$ is given by $c = n + 1$.

Having written that, I am rather conviced that the proper scaling factor should be $n+1$ instead of $n$.

Comment: Thanks. I understand the difference in domains, but I don't understand your second and third paragraph. In the second paragraph, you assume a PMF that only depends on $n$ and each mass point needs to have a probability $1/n$. That's okay, but in this case, our binomial PMF does depend on $\theta$ and $h$. As a consequence, the probability allocation is not uniform. In the third paragraph, I'm not sure I understand the part where you said `Integrating $1/n$ from 0 to 1 does not yield 1 but $1/n$`. Are you sure there is not a typo there?

Comment: @Robert: I edited and hopefully clarified the answer.

Comment: Thank you. Now I understand what you're saying. Well, the calculation looks alright, even though I found another instance of multiplication by $n$ (not $n+1$) in another tutorial. It is possible that one was taken from the other.